# Are there other ways to tie a character's name to a mythological character's name without using the same name or anagram?

Tags: creative-writing, naming

Are there other ways to tie a character's name to a mythological character's name without using the same name or anagram?

Sometimes, we just use the same name like Loki, Detective Loki, or an anagram like Detective Kilo, or whatever you want, but what are some subtler ways to achieve the same thing, and could you give a few examples of those other alternative techniques to achieve the same thing symbolically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the etymological roots of the name.  For instance, Loki is believed to be derived from the same Old Norse roots for their words "Knots", "Loops" , or "Cobwebs" and maybe related to the fact that he was originally credited with inventing fishing net as well as being blamed for tangles, knots, and loops, and -because of the net's similar design to webs- spiders.   If Loki wanted to travel incognito... yet have a name that would signal to his closest supporters... he might take a name that fits these themes.

Or look to mythology for other names.  For example, Loki was believed to have taken the identity of an elderly woman named Thokk (Old Norse for "Thanks") who refused to weep for the deceased Baldr, thus condemning him to Hel... and since Baldr's death was the prophesized inciting event for Ragnarök, Loki began it... though it's not helped that he killed Baldr (according to myth, Baldr could be resurrected if he was wept for by all).

Answer (score 3):

Some more ideas:

- Nest the name inside another: "Alloki"
- Use it as a last, or middle name. This has the advantage that you can keep the connection a secret for some time, even after introducing the character.

Comment: In the TV show "Vikings" as an example of the first option. There is a character named "Floki" who is, according to another character, not named after the norse god Loki. But he has very similar characteristics. He is physically weak but causes a lot of strife through intrigue and is at a later point subjected to an unpleasant situation that mimics one the mythological Loki had to endure.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can rhyme, or just spell it differently. Instead of Loki, use Moki, or Noki, or Loti, or Logi, or Lochee. If you want to be sure people get it, have another not-so-clever character make fun with the rhyme; "Logi like Loki".

Combine that with the right personality traits, of course.